# Getting custom workitem handlers into jBPM 6 docker images

Tags: jboss, docker, jbpm

I've been recently taking my first steps with jBPM 6, and managed to get things running nicely with a local install.

I then tried bringing the same stuff up using Docker for portability of my demo, with success, except in one area.

When installing the local version of jBPM 6.2.0.Final, 4 custom work item handlers are automatically added to the workbench. Log, WebService, Rest and Service Task, which I have used within my processes.

When installing either the jbpm-workbench:6.2.0.Final or jbpm-workbench-showcase:6.2.0.Final these custom work items do now appear, and I cannot work out where to copy CustomWorkItemHandlers.conf and drools.session.conf in my image extension Dockerfile in order to git it to pick them up (or if that will be sufficient, or if a .wid file will be necessary as well, or what.

I should also say, that I'm doing everything in the Workbench, so far I haven't had to write or change any Java code at all, and so I'd like to get the Docker version working in exactly the same way.

If anyone has any insights, I'd be really grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was being stupid, and had forgotten that somewhere along the line, I had actually edited the WorkDefinitions.wid file for the repository I was using through the workbench, and added lines to make it like the following:

```
import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.ObjectDataType;

[
  [
    "name" : "Email",
    "parameters" : [
      "From" : new StringDataType(),
      "To" : new StringDataType(),
      "Subject" : new StringDataType(),
      "Body" : new StringDataType()
    ],
    "displayName" : "Email",
    "icon" : "defaultemailicon.gif"
  ],

  [
    "name" : "Log",
    "parameters" : [
      "Message" : new StringDataType()
    ],
    "displayName" : "Log",
    "icon" : "defaultlogicon.gif"
  ],

  [
    "name" : "WebService",
    "parameters" : [
        "Url" : new StringDataType(),
         "Namespace" : new StringDataType(),
         "Interface" : new StringDataType(),
         "Operation" : new StringDataType(),
         "Parameter" : new StringDataType(),
         "Endpoint" : new StringDataType(),
         "Mode" : new StringDataType()
    ],
    "results" : [
        "Result" : new ObjectDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "WS",
    "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png"
  ],

  [
    "name" : "Rest",
    "parameters" : [
        "Url" : new StringDataType(),
        "Method" : new StringDataType(),
        "ConnectTimeout" : new StringDataType(),
        "ReadTimeout" : new StringDataType(),
        "Username" : new StringDataType(),
        "Password" : new StringDataType()
    ],
    "results" : [
        "Result" : new ObjectDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "REST",
    "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png"
  ]

]
```

Once I did that again, then it was fine. So obvously, for Docker images it can be pre-added to the repository or added afterwards, possibly by automation.